# Telnet to AWS SMTP port times out

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, telnet

I'm running `telnet email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com 25` on OS X terminal to connect to the AWS SES Endpoint but it keeps saying 'Operation timed out'. This is as specified in the AWS SES [troubleshooting page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-issues.html).

I had the same result on my home network as well as corporate network. Any ideas why this might be/how to fix it?

Comment: Did you open port 25 in the security group assigned to the EC2 instance? Is there an actual SMTP service running on that server on port 25? Did you open the port in any firewall software running on the server? Does `telnet localhost 25` work when you are logged onto the instance via `ssh`?

Comment: Don't use port 25.  It's very common to find that port blocked in all kinds of environments.  [Use port 587 or 2587](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-connect.html).  Does that work better?

Comment: 'Telnet command not found' when logged into the instance. But using 587 or 2587 worked!